# How to add data to an nested array inside a json object

Tags: arrays, json, react-hooks, jscript, use-state

My state object looks like this:

```
const [result,setResult] = useState({
  series: [
      {
          name: 'Budget',
          data: [5000, 3000, 5000, 7000, 6000, 4000]
      },
      {
          name: 'Income',
          data: [8000, 1000, 7000, 2000, 5000, 3000]
      }
  ]
})
```

Now I want to append some data to the `data` array in the first `series` object

```
{
   name: 'Budget',
   data: [5000, 3000, 5000, 7000, 6000, 4000]
}
```

I try to do so with:

```
function addNumber(){
  setResult([...result.series[0].data,45]) 
}
```

But it doesn't work. Are there any suggestions or solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Its better to use immutable js to update nested data, you can do it this way using immutableJs:

```
setResult(immutable.setIn(result, ['series', 0, 'data'], result.series[0].data.concat(45)))
```

or

```
setResult(immutable.updateIn(result, ['series', 0, 'data'], array => array.concat(45)))
```

A link to immutable js documentation
https://immutable-js.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/

Comment: Its a package and you have to install it first, then require it
https://www.npmjs.com/package/immutable

Comment: thanks, but I just changed the library I used, and now it's way easier